# Web Browser's Tolerance of Seemingly Malformed files

Tags: javascript, html, web, language-agnostic

What is the **history** of browser tolerance of what appears to me as "malformed" code? By contrast, traditional programming languages are very intolerant of seemingly trivial errors (ex. missing ';', newlines at end of files for ANSI C, forgetting an import for ArrayList in Java, having the line "5;" without a left-hand assignment)?

### What I mean by apparently malformed code

The other day I was generating HTML pages with JSP and when viewing the output I thought "Wow, that table looks awful, better style it." *So I go to the .jsp file, look for the <table> tag, looking for the <table> tag, and ....... its not there*. Had the thead's, tr's, td's, tfoot's but no table wrapping up them.

Coming from other programming languages (.NET languages, C, Java, Ocaml, etc...) the idea that my web browser, *all* common web browsers, accept broken html still surprises me. Some of the cases where it does this I can understand, for example if it doesn't recognize a cutting edge new experimental HTML9 tag. But I'm still struggling to understand why browsers will accept errors in HTML, CSS, or Javascript like defining rows outside of a table or calling functions that are undefined. In ANSI C, if I forget a newline at the end of my file the compiler will scream at me a minimal of two times before failing to compile! Yet Chrome, IE, and Mozilla seems to let HTML, CSS, and Javascript get away with murder.

Comment: backwards-compatibility of non-existent standards, basically

Comment: Mainly because it's very hard for a browser to enforce strict parsing rules when it would break >99% of existing web sites. Look up XHTML for a (failed) attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: I think the qn is not a pure opinion qn, but it would be improved if you gave a real, but small example of incoherent HTML, which could be used as the basis for a much more specific answer than the one I gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rhumborl wrote: "backwards-compatibility of non-existent standards, basically", which is simplistic but true.

The Wikipedia overview article on the [history of web browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_web_browser) says, after summarising the browser wars:

> The wars put the Web in the hands of millions of ordinary PC users, but showed how commercialization of the Web could stymie standards efforts. Both Microsoft and Netscape liberally incorporated proprietary extensions to HTML in their products, and tried to gain an edge by product differentiation, leading to the acceptance of the Cascading Style Sheets proposed by Håkon Wium Lie over Netscape's JavaScript Style Sheets (JSSS) by W3C.

To put the problem in a nutshell, the various browser vendors were all trying to follow a strategy of embrace-and-extend, each adopting the new features of the others as soon as they achieved widespread use, and then adding their own 'improvements'.  Only with the failure of Silverlight and the rise of HTML5 do we see a clear end of this era.